# What would be a better method of accessing user data?

Tags: laravel

Long story short, I need to display user data in Laravel within my Vue routerview. I'm wondering what method is better to use as they both work for my case.

Solution 1: Declare `:user="{{ Auth::user()->toJson() }}` on the routerview and prop it to the view so I can use user.id, user.name etc. ?

Solution 2: Using Laravel Passport to create access tokens & Axios to make an Ajax call to the /api/user path?

What do you think of both these methods? Which one would you recommend? And why?

Comment: Where does `this.auth` come from?  With a single page app, it's definitely better to have a central store for this type of data rather than requesting user information repeatedly from the API.

Comment: @Devon I declare auth="{{ Auth::user()->toJson() }}" on the routerview. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to use JSON.parse if you use v-bind.

Comment: When I just use v-bind-user="{{ Auth::user()->toJson() }} on my routerview the user object returns empty.

Comment: it'd be `v-bind:user` or short hand `:user`, not `v-bind-user`.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for letting me know. So what would be more acceptable, this or using Laravel Passport?

Comment: That is pretty opinion based and entirely depends on your use case.  Using Laravel's auth scaffolding like this is probably more simple, but using JWT/oauth may give you more options later on.

Comment: @Devon What kind of options would that be?

Comment: Mobile apps, third party apps, external services that consume your API, etc.